# Merits of Entity Framework when not using migrations

Tags: entity-framework

I've got limited experience with Entity Framework, but the times I've used it I've always taken the code-first migrations approach. I've recently been hired at a job where they use Entity Framework, and they've said that they want to retain control over their SQL table structure by manually creating their tables. However, they also manually create C# classes and their respective EntityTypeConfigurations.

So given my limited experience and understanding of the Entity Framework, this has made me curious of some things. What are some examples of things one might sacrifice or risk by relinquishing control of the SQL table structure to the Entity Framework code-first migrations? And when writing both the code side of things and the database side of things manually, not letting the framework generate either side of the object-relational mapping, is there any merit left in using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

This is largely opinion based, and I wouldn't be surprised to see this question closed.

Having said that, your schema generation and maintenance is not what EF (or any ORM) is for. An ORM's main function is to relieve you of writing SQL in your code, and writing the plumbing needed to send it to the database, and extract the results to an object you can work with. An ORM does all that for you. So even at the scenario you described, using EF will still be beneficial.

Comment: I mean, most stackoverflow questions are closed, so I wouldn't be surprised either :P

Thanks for the answer though!